# Show that $ |f(b)-f(a)| ≤ \frac 12|b-a|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm trying to show that for:

> $f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{1+x^2})$ then $|f(b)-f(a)|\le \frac{1}{2}|b-a|$, for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Honestly. I'm pretty lost here. How would I even start this off?

Comment: Mean Value Theorem

Comment: I got an intuitive feeling that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156793/how-to-prove-that-ln1x2x-given-that-x0) can help you solve it apart form MVT.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Mean value theorem. For any $a$ and $b$ the MVT says there exists $c$ such that
$$
f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)
$$
Take absolute values of both sides of the above. Your mission is to show that $|f'(c)|$ is at most $1/2$, no matter what $c$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by the Mean Value Theorem,

$\frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{|b-a|}=|f'(x)|$ for some $a<x<b$

Now it just remains to show that $f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

You can find the maximum of $f'(x)$ by taking derivative of $f'(x)$ (find $f''(x)$)

Now before you take the derivative, you should notice that

$\ln(\sqrt{1+x^2})= \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+x^2)$

that helps in making the derivative easier

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it :) .